# CRM 2011/2013. stopping header displaying "new contact" or "new property" etc

Tags: header, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM 2013 and 2011 I have some data that I've imported in. When you view the records they have, at the top in big letters "New Contact" or "New Account" etc depending on their type. I've looked at the form header and tried adding a field there (that I want displayed) thinking that it defaults to to new whatever since there is no other field. This is not the case. Primarily I'm using 2013, but the same thing happens in 2011 as well.

I tested to see if it's just for the imported records, but it also happens when I create new ones. Is this something that CRM does usually, and if so is there a way to tell it to display something else?

Comment: can you add a screenshot to explain better? thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like you have imported data without filling in the primary field ag Account Name or Contact Full Name (this ought to be filled in as long as you import a first or last name)

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking about is the way CRM displays the name of the Entity in the page title and the form header.  If so, this is a (completely unsupported) function that I call to update the name of an entity in CRM 2011.  I'm guessing it won't work for 2013 though.

```
setDisplayName: function (name) {
    // Updates the Document Title
    var title = parent.document.title;
    var start = title.indexOf(':') + 2;
    var end = title.lastIndexOf('-') - 1;
    parent.document.title = title.substring(0, start) + name + title.substring(end);

    // Sets the div Name
    document.getElementById("form_title_div").childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerText = name;
},
```

You can call it on the onLoad of the Entity and clear it, or set it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

What OP wanted was to remove the New Case label when creating a new Case (or any other entity)[image]

I've done this today in CRM 2013 with this line

```
//Remove New Case label
document.getElementById("FormTitle").style.visibility = "hidden";
```